# Unable to override Superfish styles in Zen theme

Tags: theming, navigation

I am using a zen subtheme and a superfish menu. I am trying to override the background colours of the menu but am not having luck in IE8. I've tried clearing the cache but still no luck.

Do you have any idea why? Why isn't IE8 recognising the pages.css style sheet?

This style sheet is being picked up by IE8.

#### superfish/style/default.css

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-default li,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default.sf-navbar {
  background: red;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-default li li {
  background: pink;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-default li:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default li.sfHover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:focus,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:active {
  background: green;
  outline: 0;
}
```

While this style sheet is being picked up by FireFox (this is what I want).

#### mytheme/css/pages.css

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-default li,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default.sf-navbar {
  background: orange;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-default li li {
  background: yellow;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-default li:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default li.sfHover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:focus,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-default a:active {
  background: grey;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: version D6 or D7??

Answer (score 1):

It was just a matter of selection the Aggregate and compress CSS files option under Bandwidth optimization